# User Location Retrieval Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, maps, cllocationmanager, info.plist

I am trying to get the user location in my app that I have built following a tutorial on iOS 9. I have done it exactly the same (as far as I know) as the instructor in the video and for the guy in the video it works but for me it doesn't. First I constructed a CLLocationManager like this:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Then I made sure to add the following lines of code in viewDidLoad():

```
locationManager.delegate = self        
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest        
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()        
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Finally, I created a method to receive updated locations:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(locations)
}
```

So far the window pops up in my app that asks if the user wants to allow usage of the location, but when I press Allow, nothing starts printing out in the console window. I made sure to set NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in Info.plist, still not working though, and I also added the CoreLocation.framework thing. Since I am quite new to Swift, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should implement the `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)` delegate method and call `startUpdatingLocation` once your use of location is authorised

Comment: Ok, never mind about this question, I solved it. Silly mistake, I was using the simulator and didn't simulate movement. I am a complete newbie

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added CLLocationManagerDelegate to your class declaration.

Comment: I did, it is there

Answer (score 0):

Just check your authorisation status in this delegate. If its authorised you can update your location. Might be your authorisation has failed at the initial launch. So you should either provide the location access from the settings or delete the app and then install again!!

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse ||  status == .AuthorizedAlways {
        print("permissions granted")
    }else{
        print(status)
    } 
}
```

Comment: When I ran this code without the else statement, nothing printed out in the console when I pressed allow, but when I deleted the program, added the else statement, and ran the app again, this printed out to the console:

Comment: "CLAuthorizationStatus"

Comment: Actually that prints out before I even press Allow

Comment: Nothing new prints out when I press it

Comment: If its only printing "CLAuthorizationStatus", it means your app is not authorised for "AuthorizedWhenInUse" or "AuthorizedAlways". Recheck your .plist file to confirm, you are adding the correct keyword "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription".

Comment: Ok, now that works, but still not running didUpdateLocations

Comment: It says "permissions granted" in the console, which is what I want, but still it does not print out what I want it to in the other method

Comment: I have tested your code. Its working like a charm. Can you provide me your full code, so that I can figure out the issue?

Comment: It might be you are using the simulator. So you should either use an actual device or try simulating your location from the simulator.